# MVC 3 Edit data in a IEnumerable Model View

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to edit a list of items in a strongly-typed razor view. The templates don't give me the option to edit a list of objects in a single view so I merged the List view with the Edit view. I only need to edit one boolean field in a checkbox.
The problem is that i cant get the data back to the controller. How do i do it? `FormCollection`? `Viewdata`? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

**Models:**

```
public class Permissao
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public TipoPermissao TipoP { get; set; }
    public bool HasPermissao { get; set; }
    public string UtilizadorID { get; set; }
}

public class TipoPermissao
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public int IndID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller Actions:**

```
    public ActionResult EditPermissoes(string id)
    {
        return View(db.Permissoes.Include("TipoP").Where(p => p.UtilizadorID == id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPermissoes(FormCollection collection)
    {
        //TODO: Get data from view
        return RedirectToAction("GerirUtilizadores");
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MIQ.Models.Permissao>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditPermissoes";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>

    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            Indicador
        </th>
        <th>
            Nome
        </th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.HasPermissao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoP.IndID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoP.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TipoP.Descricao)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table> 
<p>
   <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
 </p>
}
```

Comment: Is it not coming back to the FormCollection at all?

Comment: I think it is, just dont know how to get it from the FormCollection.

Comment: I do this: var value = collection["item.HasPermissao"];

Comment: and i get this: "false,true,false,false,true,false,false" and only have 5 items. Its puts an extra false for each true!? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do i do it? FormCollection? Viewdata?

None of the above, use the view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditPermissoes(IEnumerable<Permissao> model)
{
    // loop through the model and for each item .HasPermissao will contain what you need
}
```

And inside your view instead of writing some loops use editor templates:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            Indicador
        </th>
        <th>
            Nome
        </th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Permissao.cshtml`):

```
@model Permissao
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.HasPermissao)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TipoP.IndID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TipoP.Nome)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TipoP.Descricao)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yep! This works great and will help in future coding! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov i have repeated your instructions and i have a weird exception, like this 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DomainModel.Models.MoneyExchangeMessage]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'DomainModel.Models.MoneyExchangeMessage'.

Comment: @IamStalker, I guess you passed the wrong type to the view or the view is strongly typed to the wrong type.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't, i have checked it, if you want i would put it as a question, off course if you have the time to look at it?

Comment: Sure, you could start a new question.