# passing multiple values from view to controller to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model Question

```
public class Question
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int SystemAnswer { get; set; }
    public int StudentAnswer { get; set; }


}
```

In the view I have

```
@foreach (string[] item in ViewBag.Questions1 as List<string[]>)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentAnswer)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentAnswer)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Where `ViewBag.Questions1` is a list of x number of strings

The controller

```
public ActionResult theAnswer(Question question) 
{        
    int blah = question.StudentAnswer;
    ViewBag.test = blah.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

The controller should pass the `question.StudentAnswer` int values to another view; however, it only passes the first value of `question.StudentAnswer`.  How I can make it pass all the values of `question.StudentAnswer`??

Comment: It's an `int`. It only has one value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to pass in multiple Questions at once, so you need to have multiple questions in your view as well, and I can't see the controller of the Questions view....

In fact, I would get rid of the ViewBag business and pass it in as a viewmodel, that will make things much simpler

See this for example:
[MVC 3 Edit data in a IEnumerable Model View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010038/mvc-3-edit-data-in-a-ienumerable-model-view)