# How to validate IEnumerable<string> property in Model in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have model, that has IEnumerable property.

```
public class SendEmailModel
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(Helper.DefaultEmailValidationPattern, ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidValue", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(i18n))]
    public IEnumerable<string> Recipients { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(Helper.DefaultInputValidationPattern, ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidValue", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(i18n))]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { LoadingElementId = "loadingPane" }, new { id = "SendEmailForm"}))
{
    <div class="custom-validation-summary-errors"></div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Recipients, i18n.To):
    </div>

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Recipients, "String")
        </div>
    }

    <div class="mt20">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Subject, i18n.Subject):
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Subject, "String")
    </div>

   ...

   <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
}
```

But when posting the form validation doesn't work. And after posting i get ModelState.IsValid - false.

**Edit:**
I`m trying to make use of unobtrusive validation. Validation for subject is working (user cannot post form with invalid subject)

The for loop will be replaced by jquery adding/deleting of Recipients.

Comment: can you post complete view and action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use validation data annotations on `IEnumerable<T>` typed properties. You can create a wrapper class instead as follows:

```
public class Recipient
{
    [RegularExpression(Helper.DefaultEmailValidationPattern, ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidValue", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(i18n))]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your main ViewModel,

```
public class SendEmailModel
{
    [Required]
    public IEnumerable<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Now you can create an [editor template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) for your `Recipient` class by creating a partial view bound to the `Recipient`, like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
```

Now, in your main view bound to `SendEmailModel`, you can just do this:

```
@Html.EditorForModel
```

This will create an editor for each property. In this case, the property is of type `IEnumerable<Recipient>`, so it will create an editor template (as previously defined) for each item in that list. All validations will be automatically applied.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010038/mvc-3-edit-data-in-a-ienumerable-model-view) is a similar discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea but how about creating a bypass property?

could probably do something like

```
string RecipienctsCsv {
 get
 {
   return string.Join(', ', Recipiencts);
 }
}
```

Then again you don't show enough code to verify wether that would be an option for you or not. Another option would be to Extend the HtmlHelper to make it work for IEnumerable